# How to retrieve the name of a contact with its number from the contact list in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to access the contact list to get the telephone number of a contact.
I am using the PhoneNumberChooserTask class to do that, and it returns me the number but not the name of the contact, which would be useful for many reasons. 
Is there any way to retrieve both information?

Thank you,
Oscar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible. There is currently an outstanding feature request on the App Hub: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/68349.aspx

Comment: I read that this feature should be available in the Mango update.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There will be much better access to the Contact database in Mango.